# error in sequelize and mysql connection in testing

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, sequelize.js

I have an application written in nodejs for backend and sequelize for connecting to mysql.
when I run my app in and send requests to endpoint every thing is ok.
but the problem is in test mode. when i try to test my endpoints with supertest I get a really annoying error that says:
`[SequelizeConnectionError]: authSwitch.authSwitchRequest is not a function`
the full error message is:

````
    Attempted to log "mysql could not connect! ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: authSwitch.authSwitchRequest is not a function
        at ConnectionManager.connect (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:126:17)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at ConnectionManager._connect (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:318:24)
        at D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:250:32
        at ConnectionManager.getConnection (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:280:7)
        at D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:613:26
        at Sequelize.authenticate (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:867:5) {
      parent: TypeError: authSwitch.authSwitchRequest is not a function
          at ClientHandshake.handshakeResult (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\client_handshake.js:150:22)
          at ClientHandshake.execute (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:39:22)
          at Connection.handlePacket (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:425:32)
          at PacketParser.onPacket (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
          at PacketParser.executeStart (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
          at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
          at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:312:12)
          at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:287:9)
          at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:226:10),
      original: TypeError: authSwitch.authSwitchRequest is not a function
          at ClientHandshake.handshakeResult (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\client_handshake.js:150:22)
          at ClientHandshake.execute (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:39:22)
          at Connection.handlePacket (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:425:32)
          at PacketParser.onPacket (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
          at PacketParser.executeStart (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
          at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\Nodejs\FamiShop\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
          at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:312:12)
          at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:287:9)
          at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:226:10)
    }".  ```
I searched the internet but I could not find a solution for this.
can you help me?
````

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this problem while setting up my test suite.

The issue was that I forgot to use await while creating the database connection. I had something like this:

```
    connection.client = new Sequelize(connectionString('ems'), {
        dialect: 'mysql',
        .....
    })

    connection.client.authenticate()
```

I changed it like so:

```
    connection.client = new Sequelize(connectionString('ems'), {
        dialect: 'mysql',
        .....
    })

    await connection.client.authenticate() // await this
```

That did the trick.

Right after fixing that I ran into another annoyance: *Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.* That was fixed by adding the following line in the test file.

```
afterAll(() => connection.client.close())
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey first you need to install sequelize  command like this `npm install sequelize sequelize-cli`

and run this command `sequelize init` to run this command it will create some files in your backend folder, like **config, models migrations, seeders**

#and then in the config you will hve your connection code like this:

```
    {
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "*****",
    "database": "your project name in the database",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

and then run your back-end it will create all the tables that you provide in the model file.